# How to best resolve elusive python segmentation fault?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, wget, popen

I have a python code running on crontab every 15 minute since three years. During the last year however the script have terminated twice with segmentation fault. I've managed to track down the problem to calling wget using Popen from the subprocesses module but fail to move on from there. Now failing twice in this many runs may sound like nothing to cry about, however it still annoys me quite, thus any advice on how to proceed from here to resolve the issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could use python `wget.py` module instead of the executable. changing technologies sometimes solves problem (and it's better to stay in python rather than calling an external process)

Comment: Python cannot give you a "segmentation fault". At worst it will throw an exception. This is happening outside of python.